# Socket is closed from within TimerTask.run()

Tags: java

I have a socket to server. With the help of TimerTask, every 1 second it queries server and reads response through output/input stream. However, I am getting the error *Socket is closed*.

```
try (
        // create TCP socket for the given hostName, remote port PortNumber
        Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);

        // Stream writer to the socket
        PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        // Stream reader from the socket
        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()))
) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Query the server.
                out.println("?");
                // read response from the socket
                String receivedText = in.readLine(); // ** error here
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
```

Here is server socket:

```
while (((receivedText = in.readLine()) != null)) {
    if (receivedText.equals("?")) {
        out.println(getCurrentState());
    }
}

// close the connection socket
connectSocket.close();
```

However if I use while(true) and Thread.sleep(1000) instead of TimerTask, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by putting your `BufferedReader in` into `try`-with-resources block your `BuferedReader` is automatically closed right after the "main" thread leaves main section of `try` block. That happens right after calling `timer.schedule()`. And the `Timer` thread started by calling `timer.schedule()` therefore sees later on when triggered only closed socket/file descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

TimerTask runs in a separate thread, and as explained [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1150694?start=0&tstart=0), although Socket is thread safe, it is not recommended to use multiple threads to read/write to Socket connections simultaneously.

So, in the above example, Socket and BufferedReader both should be local to the task as shown below:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try (
                // create TCP socket for the given hostName, remote port
                // PortNumber
                Socket echoSocket = new Socket(hostName, port);
                // Stream writer to the socket
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                // Stream reader from the socket
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));) {
            // Query the server.
            out.println("?");
            // read response from the socket
            String receivedText = in.readLine(); // ** error here
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```